# mysql: table structure for this numerical database?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to define a table structure/schema for this simulation database. I have been thinking days about this and how to do normalization (not sure if it is even possible):

using a very broad example and the values could be anything

```
runset | input value | device name | temperature | voltage | measurement name | value
```

Presently, I can only think of 1st Normalization and that's it ...

Any ideas? a lot of the values can be unique inside this table and can reach up to 60 million rows.

Comment: What's going to help is if some of these columns are ever derived elsewhere.. you'd be better off posting those sources too, especially if they are tables. Establishing relationships, what would be unique, if you expect duplicates, etc.. would be good to include in your post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what you have is just about right.

Its a table of observations so just put your data in a table just as you described.

You don't actually need to give a table a primary key, and in your case it doesn't look like you need one, but some people are deeply uncomfortable with this so a system generated "ID" column to act as primary key might be needed.

In addition you might optionally have (but only if you identify an actual need):

- a "runset" table to hold details of each run such as date, time, operator etc.
- a "measurement" table to fully describe each measurement type.
- a "device" table to hold details on each device (make, model, serial number etc.)

Using "device name" and "measurement name" as primary/foreign keys would work just fine to there is no need to mess with generated "id"s on these tables.

A well designed schema should look simple and obvious, do not mistake complication and deviousness for good design.